# How to preview html in netbean 8.1 version?

Tags: editor, netbeans-8

I am trying to shift Dreamweaver to Netbeans 8.1, I want to preview html code but I cannot find any short cut or any icon to preview. Should I install plugin for it?
 I tried this plugin http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/51003/html-preview but donot work for 8.1.

Anyone have Idea about it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is no "native" support for HTML preview in NetBeans. You can run (open) the file in browser from IDE. How to do it depends on type of project but generally if you right click on the file in NetBeans, there should be something like "Run File"

Answer (score 0):

For Netbeans 8.2

Option 1:
Right-click and choose "View" from the context menu.

Option 2:
Go to    Preferences > Keymap, search for "View", assign a key shortcut of your choice to "View" that belongs to "System" category.

"Customizing" the toolbox panel by adding "Web browser" icon to it didn't work for me: instead of displaying my HTML file it opens a Netbeans' front page, bragging how brilliant this IDE is. Very helpful indeed.